# Is there an equivalent of ie conceptual content in safari/firefox

Tags: ionic-framework

On internet explorer, i can press F12 to access developper tools. There is a conceptual content tab when i am working on a ionic app.
is there something equivalent on safari or firefox ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firefox: Toggle Developer Toolbar ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts)):

> Windows / OSX / Linux: Shift + F2

Safari: Enabling Web Inspector ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html))

> To start using Web Inspector, you must first enable the Develop menu. To do so, enable the “Show Develop menu in menu bar” setting found in Safari’s preferences under the Advanced pane, as shown in Figure 1-1.
>
> Then Command-Option-I to access console

Go on reading on the last link for usefull information on how to debug an ios app from desktop since you are woking on a Ionic app.

Comment: I know about this. What i want is conceptual content